# Jquery .load 304 not-modified

Tags: ajax, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Okay, I am loading a div from one page to my current page with the .load function:

```
<code>
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
         var myUrl = "test.php"
      $("#tags-load").load(myUrl + " #tags");
      $("#share-load").load(myUrl + " .shareinload");
      $("#comments-load").load(myUrl + " #comments");     
         }); 
</code>
```

Here is my problem, the above method doesn't work in IE 8 and lower, but does work in IE9 and Chrome and Firefox.

I did a bit of messing around and found that the above code can work in IE8 BUT only if I am not calling any images from the test.php (neither img tag images nor background images). Then I checked the HTTP codes to see if I was getting an error there, it turns out I was getting a 304 error when ever an image was being loaded. This led me to believe that IE8 must be having some kind of hangup while caching the images. So I altered my code to turn off caching for jquery requests:

```
<code>
$.ajax({
  cache: false
  });
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
     var myUrl = "test.php"
  $("#tags-load").load(myUrl + " #tags");
  $("#share-load").load(myUrl + " .shareinload");
  $("#comments-load").load(myUrl + " #comments");     
     });
</code>
```

Despite altering the code, I am still getting 304 errors. I'm pretty new to Jquery and I'm stuck here, if anyone could help me find a solution to this it would be greatly appreciated,

thanks

Comment: Are you doing it cross domains? that would explain why :)

Comment: It's same domain, sorry I failed to mention that in the post.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to make 3 page requests, if its the same page.

Could you try this:

```
var myUrl = "test.php";
$.ajax({
  url: myUrl,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    var tags = $('#tags',html).html();
    var shareinload = $('.shareinload',html).html();
    var comments = $('#comments',html).html();
    $("#tags-load").html(tags);
    $("#share-load").html(shareinload);
    $("#comments-load").html(comments);
  }
});
```

Comment: I knew there was a better way to do that, thanks for making it more streamlined (it loads much faster now). But my problem with the 304 errors still persists in IE8. I know a lot of people have had problems with using .load in IE8 has anyone come across a workaround for this?

Comment: Well i usually get the error, its when the recieving code contains errors which breaks the loaded content. Does it send ok, but fail on the get?

Comment: Yes, like you're saying it sends okay but fails to get. I tried to use some simple code in the test.php and I was getting 304 errors in all browsers:
<code>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tags">Tags</div>
<div class="shareinload">Share</div>
<div id="comments">Comments</div>
</body>
</html>
</code>